# How to find a new JBoss Application Server 7 server in eclipse?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I want to launch my application with JBoss AS7. Normally I'll go to Window->Preferences->Server->RuntimeEnvironments and Add JBoss 7.0 Runtime. But I can't find JBoss AS 7.0 Runtime. I have installed the JBOSS Community with JBoss AS 3.2, ... 6.0 but where is 7? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed run JBoss Application Server 7 with Eclipse, but you will find it easiest to do so with JBoss Tools. There's a helpful guide posted to the JBoss community per the following: [Starting JBoss AS from Eclipse with JBoss Tools](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Starting+JBoss+AS+from+Eclipse+with+JBoss+Tools)

There's another useful guide on the JBoss Tools site: [How to use JBoss AS 7 Beta 2 with JBoss Tools & Developer Studio](https://community.jboss.org/community/tools/blog/2011/04/18/how-to-use-jboss-as-7-with-jboss-tools-developer-studio)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Eclipse supports JBoss AS 7... You may need to run it manually for now.

Comment: Earlier versions lacked the AS 7 runtime, but this has been resolved.